# What is the simplest way to associate mailto URLs with the hotmail web site?

Tags: windows-vista, hotmail, mailto

Family computer support question: I have a relative who's a hotmail user. I'd like to setup his machine (IE 8 Vista) so that when he clicks on a mailto URL it opens a new page/tab for composing mail in the normal hotmail mail composing window. Introducing a new progam like Windows Mail is way too complicated. It needs to be dead simple. Do I need "Live Mail" to do this? Or is there something even simpler than that?

Comment: Unable to understand why you wrote about family/relative. Its right or wrong, you could have asked it directly. Hotmail is feature-rich and faster than Gmail. So, Hotmail is no longer a shame..

Comment: @Sachin it's just his reasoning - a lot of grandparents can't handle change to their computer well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Officially Windows does no longer support "mailto webmail", but that doesn't mean it cannot be done.

i'm using Gmail as my default client in Windows 7 with IE8, here is what i did:

download and import this [registry file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/network-sharing/5851d1237129010-webmail-default-mail-client-mailtoyahoo.reg) (credit to limneos at sevenforums.com), which is written with Yahoo! Mail in mind.

go to **Default Programs** > **Set your default programs** > **Internet Explorer** > **Choose defaults for this program**, under **Protocols** MAILTO is now available, check the box and **Save**.

right now, all mailto links will open Internet Explorer with Yahoo! Mail/Compose, to change this, open the registry editor and navigate to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Yahoo.Mailto\shell\open\command
```

double click the default value, the following part (url) of the value data has to be replaced:

```
http://us.mc01g.mail.yahoo.com/mc/compose?.rand=947383854&to=%1
```

for Gmail, i'm using this URL instead:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=%1
```

for Hotmail use this URL:

```
http://hotmail.msn.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%1
```

voilá, Hotmail as default email client in Windows.

p.s.: i have tested Hotmail as default email client in only in Windows 7 & IE8, but this workaround should work for Vista just as well. i don't use Firefox, but i'm pretty sure this can be done with FF as well if you change the value data of the default key accordingly (FF may require %s instead of %1 at the end):

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe http://hotmail.msn.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%1
```

of course you will have to associate FF with the MAILTO protocol.

*note: as usual, you should backup the registry before making changes.*

Comment: Sigh, this sounded promising, but didn't work for me on Vista. There's a dialog that comes up asking if it's ok to launch IE not in "protected mode". Clicking on "Allow" seems to do nothing.

Comment: hmm ... it works grand for me in XP and Windows 7 (i'm not using protected mode but Sandboxie), unfortunately i don't have the option to check it with Vista. can you try with Firefox as this browser doesn't use Protected Mode?

Comment: Update: Google provide a list of all current mailto URLs: http://code.google.com/p/mailto-chromeextension/wiki/AddCustomUrl#Examples

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP/IE8, navigate to Tools/Internet Options... | Programs
Then select "Windows Live Mail" from the dropdown box next to Email.

I have not tried this in Windows 7 or Vista.