# How Do I Configure IE8 to Open mailto: links via Hotmail / Windows Live Email Broswer Client?

Tags: internet, microsoft-outlook-2007, internet-explorer-8, email-client, mailto

I have a client that has Win XP Home SP3 and MS Office Home and Student installed (and another machine with Win7 and IE8) who wants to have mailto: links open in IE8 browser email client for his hotmail account?

When I set Internet Options/Programs to use Windows Live Email - the Outlook client still opens for clicks on mailto: links.

Anyone out there able to get this working?

Comment: This appears to be a near duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/questions/82163/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-associate-mailto-urls-with-the-hotmail-web-site

Comment: UPDATE 2011-12-28: I used various methods (sorry there were so many that I found, I don't recall which)...however I found these processes more or less buggy and/or inconsistent across machines.  I no longer support these machines, so I am sorry I won't be of further use on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how to do what you want using Chrome and Gmail.  It should be fairly evident how to adapt the method to work with IE8 and hotmail.

[Make mailto: links open in gmail in Google Chrome browser (Windows XP & Vista)](http://blog.bn.ee/2008/09/04/make-mailto-links-open-in-gmail-in-google-chrome-browser-windows-xp-and-vista/)

> #### WIndows XP
>
> In any windows explorer window (except desktop):
>
> - Go to Tools > Folder Options > File Types
> - Near the top of the list of filetypes, click on “URL:Mailto Protocol”
> - Click on “Advanced”
> - With “open” highlighted, click on “Edit”
> - Change the application to:
>
>   ```
>   "C:\Pathto\chrome.exe" https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=%1
>   ```
>
> This should all be on one line with a space between the quotation mark
>   after the path info and the https. My path was
>
> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\Brendan\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> ```
>
> To find yours, just right
>   click on a google Chrome shortcut (like the one in your start menu),
>   go to “properties” and copy the “Target” field.
>
> #### Windows Vista
>
> - Open your registry editor (Type “regedit” at your start menu)
> - Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command
> - Edit the (Default) command from whatever it is (right click and select modify) to:
>
>   ```
>   "C:\Pathto\chrome.exe" https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=%1
>   ```
>
> In Vista, your path will be something like
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Brendan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> ```
>
> with “Brendan” being your username.