# How to set mailto protocol for gmail

Tags: windows-8, gmail

I cannot select mailto protocol in default parameters for google chrome, as it is marked as unknown application.

EDIT : To clarify, I tried [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/82163/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-associate-mailto-urls-with-the-hotmail-web-site) but when I save, and I go back in Google Chrome associations, MAILTO is automatically deactivated.

I cannot either associate google chrome for mailto in the type association, as it is not defined.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ucET.jpg)

When I stumble upon a link in an application or on the web, I get the window for selecting the program, with for only choice the Windows Store.

How can I set this right, so I can open any mailto whether they're on applications or the web ?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: Yeah I've read it (it appears just below the title) but my problem is about the association : I can't find the mailto protocol in the list of association type (look for the link in the question)

Comment: Nov 2017 Chrome 62 - works differently.